# Airflow KubernetesPodOperator: pass securityContext parameter

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

Anyone could give me an example on passing some parameters as **"runAsNonRoot"** when creating a pod through **KubernetesPodOperator**?

I've tried to dig through the documentation but it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At current this does not appear to be supported in the operator.
You can see that the [`KubePodOp`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py) has an init that makes a [`PodGenerator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_generator.py). It then adds all the volumes and mounts to it before generating. This does not at any point call the only method in which you could pass a `SecurityContext` [`add_init_container`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_generator.py#L33)whose documentation appears to have been cut off mid sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a dictionary to the KubernetesPodOperator constructor with the following content:

```
security_context = {"runAsNonRoot": True}
```

You can look up the keys and value datatypes that you can pass via this dict in class "V1SecurityContext" and the linked classes *(/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/models/v1_security_context.py)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pods through KubernetesPodOperator such as in [python](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#launch) format. Here is the [list](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/workflows/kubernetes_pod_operator.py) of all parameters you can pass through KubernetesPodOperator.

I could not find a specific example on how to pass this "runAsNonRoot" parameters through KubernetesPodOperator. In [YAML](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/08/security-best-practices-kubernetes-deployment/#Apply_Security_Context_to_Your_Pods%20_and_Containers) format, pod security parameters are defined as following:

```
spec:  
  containers:  
  # specification of the pod’s containers  
  # ...  
  securityContext:  
    readOnlyRootFilesystem: true  
    runAsNonRoot: true
```