# Is it possible to have a Kubernetes cluster with privileged pods by default?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I'm creating a pod through the `KubernetesPodOperator` in Airflow. This pod should mount a Google Cloud Storage to `/mnt/bucket` using `gcsfuse`. For this, the pod is required to be started with the `securityContext` parameter, such that it can become 'privileged'.

It is [currently not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742455/airflow-kubernetespodoperator-pass-securitycontext-parameter) to pass the securityContext parameter through Airflow. Is there another way to work around this? Perhaps by setting a 'default' securityContext before the pods are even started? I've looked at creating a `PodSecurityPolicy`, but haven't managed to figure out a way.

Comment: on the cluster level , you need to configure a custom PSP that allow privileged containers

Comment: Those are allowed, but there's no way in Airflow to pass this parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate from the Mutating Admission Controller, it's also possible to deploy a DaemonSet into your cluster that mounts `/mnt/bucket` onto the host filesystem, and the the Airflow pods would use `{"name": "bucket", "hostPath": {"path": "/mnt/bucket"}}` as their `volume:`, which -- assuming it works -- would be a **boatload** less typing, and also not run the very grave risk of a Mutating Admission Controller borking your cluster and causing Pods to be mysteriously mutated

Comment: Though this sounds like a very good idea, after doing so, I'm getting the following message: `error while creating mount source path '/mnt/bucket': mkdir /mnt/bucket: read-only file system` which leads to `ContainerCannotRun`.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, since we will want some journalctl output, or to know if you can `docker run -v /mnt/bucket:/mnt/bucket -it busybox ls -la /mnt` by hand, and so forth. The devil is in the details

Answer (score 2):

A mutating admission controller would allow you to do that: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook

The ibm-cloud team has a post about it, but I've never tried writing one: https://medium.com/ibm-cloud/diving-into-kubernetes-mutatingadmissionwebhook-6ef3c5695f74 and the folks at GiantSwarm have an end-to-end example using their Grumpy admission controller: https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/creating-your-own-admission-controller/

I would use the labels, or annotations, or maybe even the image, to identify Pods launched by Airflow, and then mutate only them to set the `securityContext:` on the Pods to be the way you want.